# How to authenticate to box-api without oauth redirecting

Tags: box-api

I am trying to make a simple integration to BOX where I only access my own account. Since this is a server-side access, (the server-process calls the Box-api), having the Oauth 2.0 redirecting is a problem. 
Is there a way I could acquire a token (even manually) and use it in my code, by-passing the hassle of Oauth 2.0 and the redirection ? Or may be some other way for this kind of scenario ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you can do this with a Developer Token, but that only lasts for 1 hour.

You can also do the auth on your laptop, then put the Refresh tokens into your server in a config file, much like you might do for a database-password file (hopefully only readable by the service-account on the machine that has access to run your script).

Then build your script to take the refresh-token, go get a token pair with it, and write the new refresh token into the config file.

Comment: Thanks, I agree with you. It seems to be the best way to go around it.